# I`ve upgraded my project PHP version to 8 and upgrage PHPUnit into 9.x but coverage reports are not generated anymore?

Tags: php, phpunit, code-coverage, php-7, php-8

I tried to migrate from PHP 7 to PHP 8. I`ve updated all dependencies and then convert the PHPUnit configuration with the following command:

```
./vendor/bin/phpunit -c phpunit.xml --migrate-configuration
```

The problem is the coverage report is not generated anymore?! while all test are ok.

Here is the result phpunit.xml fild:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="https://schema.phpunit.de/9.3/phpunit.xsd"
    bootstrap="./vendor/autoload.php" 
    stopOnWarning="false" 
    verbose="false"
    backupGlobals="false" 
    backupStaticAttributes="false"
    beStrictAboutTestsThatDoNotTestAnything="true"
    beStrictAboutChangesToGlobalState="true"
    beStrictAboutOutputDuringTests="true" 
    convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
    convertNoticesToExceptions="true" 
    convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
    processIsolation="false" 
    stopOnFailure="false" 
    colors="true">
    <coverage includeUncoveredFiles="true">
        <include>
            <directory suffix=".php">./src</directory>
            <directory suffix=".php">./http-process</directory>
        </include>
        <report>
            <clover outputFile=".build/clover.xml" />
            <html outputDirectory=".build/coverage" />
        </report>
    </coverage>
    <php>
        <var name="DB_DSN" value="sqlite::memory:" />
        <var name="DB_USER" value="root" />
        <var name="DB_PASSWD" value="" />
        <var name="DB_DBNAME" value="pluf_test" />
        <var name="DB_SCHEMA" value="sqlite" />
    </php>
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="http process">
            <directory>./tests/Process/Http/</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <!-- Code coverage -->
    <logging />
</phpunit>
```

All test runs ok, but no coverage report!!.

Comment: How do you invoke PHPUnit? What is the complete output of PHPUnit when you try to generate code coverage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I googled to find the issue. finally, I`ve found a solution. In my case, xdebug configuration was the problem. There is a setting for XDebug which enables or disables features of xdebug. As you know coverage is XDebug feature. So I just enable the feature as follow:

```
xdebug.mode=debug,coverage
```

It also supports:

- off: Nothing is enabled.
- develop: Enables Development Aids including the overloaded var_dump().
- coverage: Enables Code Coverage Analysis
- debug: Enables Step Debugging.
- gcstats: Enables Garbage Collection Statistics
- profile: Enables Profiling
- trace:  Enables the Function Trace feature

for more information see [Code Coverage](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.0/code-coverage-analysis.html):

Answer (score -1):

Maybe the last `<logging />` element overrides `coverage/report`?